# how to convert json array to Dataset using C#

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have a Json String like this,

```
var JSARR=
"[[{"BRANDID":"172","VARNAME":"sd",
"ETLVARID":"1","ETLVARNAME":"Ariel_Ariel_Print",
"ISFOR":0,"ISDEP":"1"},
{"BRANDID":"172","VARNAME":"h",
"ETLVARID":"1","ETLVARNAME":"Ariel_Ariel_TV",
"ISFOR":0,"ISDEP":"0"}],

[{"BRANDID":"238","VARNAME":"df",
"ETLVARID":"1","ETLVARNAME":"Ariel_Ariel_TV",
"ISFOR":0,"ISDEP":"1"},{"BRANDID":"238","VARNAME":"dfh",
"ETLVARID":"2","ETLVARNAME":"Ariel_Ariel Detergent_Print",
"ISFOR":0,"ISDEP":"0"}]]";
```

i need to convert this json String to two datatable,
for example:

```
Datatable dt1="[{"BRANDID":"172","VARNAME":"sd",
"ETLVARID":"1","ETLVARNAME":"Ariel_Ariel_Print",
"ISFOR":0,"ISDEP":"1"},
{"BRANDID":"172","VARNAME":"h",
"ETLVARID":"1","ETLVARNAME":"Ariel_Ariel_TV",
"ISFOR":0,"ISDEP":"0"}]";

Datatable dt2="[{"BRANDID":"238","VARNAME":"df",
"ETLVARID":"1","ETLVARNAME":"Ariel_Ariel_TV",
"ISFOR":0,"ISDEP":"1"},{"BRANDID":"238","VARNAME":"dfh",
"ETLVARID":"2","ETLVARNAME":"Ariel_Ariel Detergent_Print",
"ISFOR":0,"ISDEP":"0"}]";
```

Can Any one suggest me.

Comment: This is complex task and noone will write whole code for you. First tool you will need is `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`, which will help you to convert your json string to List of List of Dictionaries (or maybe it's better to write model instead of generics). Then you will need to flatten your data and group it by id (if understood why you need TWO datatables). Finally, you will need to create your table schema (programmatically or by hand - it's your choise), and fill it with your grouped data.

Comment: Tommi Many thanks i got the output